# DHCP/Gateway done by pfSense Virtual Machine to physical network

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, routing, pfsense, dhcp-server

I have an ESXi host server that has a pfSense virtual machine within it. The VM is acting as a DHCP Server / Gateway to an internal vSwitch that is within that ESXi host.  If I use a physical NIC on that same ESXi host, and connect it to a physical switch, can I provide a separate physical workstation on that physical switch an IP address?

Answer (score 1):

If your VLAN and routing settings are correct, that shouldn't be a problem. We use pfSense as DHCP/ gateway for all our physical and VM servers (the pfSens is a VM).